# Having a cin.getline error while trying to execute

Tags: c++, string

I keep getting an error every time I try and run this code. The error Is right above my while loop (line 13 or 15ish) It has to do with my `cin.getline`.

The error states:

```
1>e:\projects (programming 1)\string\string\string.cpp(15) : error C2664:
'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>
::getline(_Elem *,std::streamsize)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char' to 'char *'
```

And yes I have tried using `cin >> ans;` and that gives me a run time error.

Thank you if you take time to help! :D

```
// Zachary Law Strings.cpp

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    char ans;
    cout << "Would you like to work with the string program? Please type 'y' or 'Y' to execute the program: ";
    cin.getline(ans, 2);
    while (ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y')
    {
        int x, i, y;
        char name[] = "Please enter your name: ";
        char answer1[80];
        string mystring, fname, lname;
        i = 0;
        y = 0;
        cout << name;
        cin.getline(answer1, 79);
        cout << endl;
        x = strlen(answer1);
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            cout << answer1[i] << endl;
            if (isspace(answer1[i]))
            {
                y = i;
            }
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << setw(80) << answer1;
        mystring = answer1;
        fname = mystring.substr(0, y);
        lname = mystring.substr(y, x);
        cout << "First name: " << fname << endl;
        cout << "Last name: " << lname << endl;
        mystring = lname + ',' + fname;
        cout << setw(80) << mystring;
        cout << "Would you like to work with the string program again? Please type 'y' or 'Y' to execute the program: ";
        cin >> ans;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You kind of forgot to ask a question. What help do you need?

Answer (score 0):

The [`std::istream::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) function requires a `char*` parameter, that is meant to be a buffer of certain size.

At least for your case reading a single char, you can provide a buffer like

```
char ans[2];

cin.getline(ans, 1); // << You only want to read a single character
```

and change the loop condition to

```
while (ans[0] == 'Y' || ans[0] == 'y') {
    // ...
}
```

The `std::istream::getline()` is supposed to write the results into a `char[]` buffer, resulting in a zero terminated C-style string.

Comment: Ok, I did what you said, and its executing now, but when I type 'Y' or 'y' it skips the entire body of my program and goes straight to return0;